# PHP not being processed inside HTML from values took from database?

Tags: php, html

I have this PHP function that needs to return the products inside the cart, products inside the cart are stored into the Database.

```
<?php
require_once 'DBHandler.php';

class getCartElementsResponse
{
    public $HTML = "<div class='cart-element'><h1>Your cart is empty!</h1></div>";
}

$DBHandler = new DBHandler();
$getCartElementsResponse = new getCartElementsResponse();

if (isset($_SESSION["userid"])) {
    $userid = $_SESSION["userid"];

    $sql = "SELECT cart.TicketQuantity, event.Name, event.Price, event.Image, user.Username, image.Description FROM cart 
    INNER JOIN event ON cart.Event_idEvent = event.idEvent 
    INNER JOIN user ON cart.User_idUsers = user.idUsers 
    INNER JOIN image ON image.Event_idEvent = event.idEvent 
    WHERE cart.User_idUsers = '$userid' AND isAcquired = 'false'";
    $result = $DBHandler->select($sql);

    if ($result) {
        $getCartElementsResponse->HTML = "";
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $getCartElementsResponse->HTML .= '
        <form action="cart.php" method="GET" class="cart-items">
            <div class="border rounded">
                <div class="row bg-white">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="$row["event.Image"]" alt="$row["image.Description"]" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h5 class="pt-2">$row["event.Name"]</h5>
                        <small class="text-secondary">$row["user.Username"]</small>
                        <h5 class="pt-2">$row["event.Price"]</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 py-3">
                        <div>
                            <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
                            <input type="text" value="$row["cart.TicketQuantity"]" class="form-control w-25 d-inline">
                            <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger mx-2" name="remove">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>';
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($getCartElementsResponse);
```

and this is the HTML/Javascript:

```
<div id="cart-elements"></div>

<script>
    includeContent("php/getCartElements.php", (r) => {
        var res = JSON.parse(r);
        var html = res["HTML"];
        document.getElementById("cart-elements").innerHTML = html;
    });
</script>
```

I don't get why it doesn't convert my PHP query results into HTML, i'm 100% sure the query works fine I tested it inside the DB, and also the code prints me the HTML on screen, **but it just doesn't convert the "$row["event.Name"]" code (and all the other ones) into the values contained in the DB.**
Can't figure out the problem, can you help me? :)
Thanks!

PS: I already tried to remove the "" inside $row[**"**event.Name**"**] (e.g.)

Comment: Why are you generating HTML and then wrapping it up in JSON? That seems a bit pointless since you're not returning any other data alongside it. It's perfectly fine to return HTML direct from your Ajax call if that's what you need

Comment: Thanks, I deleted that you are right, however you didn't answer to my question why the "$row["event.Name"]" (and all the others) are not displayed correctly with the values from my database. Is there any sintax error? They are just being printed like a string

Comment: Hint: see the difference of variable evaluation within single-quoted vs. double-quoted strings.

Comment: Already solved, but thanks for the interesting lecture